# How to concatenate all values of a pandas dataframe into an integer in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
           1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
dog cat    1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
    dog    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
    fox    1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
    jumps  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
    over   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
    the    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
```

I want to first drop all labels from both rows and columns so the df becomes:

```
1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   0
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1   1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
```

And then get then concatenate the values into one long int number so it becomes:

```
110111001011111100111111110011111111011111111100111111111011
```

Does any know a way of doing it in the shortest snippet of code possible. I appreciate the suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`apply(str.join)` + `str.cat`:

```
df.astype(str).apply(''.join, 1).str.cat(sep='')
'110111001011111100111111110011111111011111111100111111111011'
```

---

**Option 2**
`apply` + `np.add`, proposed by Wen:

```
np.sum(df.astype(str).apply(np.sum, 1))
'110111001011111100111111110011111111011111111100111111111011'
```

Comment: maybe we could use sum `np.sum(df.astype(str).apply(np.sum,1))`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC

```
''.join(str(x) for x in sum(df.values.tolist(),[]))
Out[344]: '110111001011111100111111110011111111011111111100111111111011'
```

Or

```
''.join(map(str,sum(df.values.tolist(),[])))
```

Comment: What IIUC? in your answer text

Comment: Ooh, yes thats exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Elisha512 Sorry, there was a typo in my answer which I fixed. Check both our solutions and see which one is faster on your data.